# onmousedown on a button not triggered in FirefoxOS application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox-os

My application is running perfectly under Firefox for desktop, but when I test the app on my ZTE Open C (Firefox OS 1.3) nothing append when the button is down, and the most annoying part is that onmouseup and onclick work perfectly!

I already tried to bind the event with jQuery but it doesn't work neither...

HTML:

```
<button id="0-0" onmouseup="game.release('0','0')" onmousedown="game.click()"></button>
```

Javascript:

```
Game.prototype.click = function()
{
   this.timer = window.setInterval(function(){game.time+=50;},50);
}

Game.prototype.release = function(x,y)
{
    if(game.time>200)
    {
        this.flag(x,y);
    }
    else
    {
       //some code here
    }
    game.time=0;
    clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Comment: please try this changes: `<button id="0-0" onmouseup="game.release('0','0');" onmousedown="game.click();"></button>` here you must be add `;` thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be because Firefox OS triggers touch events.

Try `ontouchstart` event in addition to `onmousedown`.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know about ontouchstart and ontouchend, it resolved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in the `mousedown` event. You will get `mouseup` notifications.

Comment: Can you explain this? Does the `mousedown` block the `mouseup` somehow by default?

Comment: I had created a JS Fiddle to explain. Please refer to this http://jsfiddle.net/j9zv0L2a/.

Comment: The behaviour is the same (so far as I can see), with or without the `preventDefault()`